# Handling DocumentClientException with BulkImport

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, bulkinsert

I am using Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor.IBulkExecutor.BulkImportAsync to insert documents as a batch. I have implemented unique constraints for my cosmos db collection. If any of the input documents violates the constraint the entire bulk import operation fails with throwing DocumentClientException. Is this an expected behaviour? Or is there a way we can handle the exceptions for failed documents and make sure the valid documents are inserted?

Comment: Since you know about the constraints, wouldn't it be safer to remove the documents that violate them before you even push them to the database?

Comment: I mentioned unique constraints for an example. How can we handle DocumentClientException that arises out of any reason for any document.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Thanks to Microsoft Document which has explained solid scenarios on the issue,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-troubleshoot-guide

This error appears when we define unique_key in addition to default id field defined by cosmos. The reason could be possible duplication of row for Unique Key in the dataset. Another possible reason, the Delta dataset which we are about to load has some of the unique keys which are already present in existing cosmos dataset.

For regular batch jobs there could be some updates happening on existing unique key itself, but we cannot update an existing unique key through batch process. As each record gets into cosmos as new record with new 'id' field value. Cosmos updates an existing record only same id field not on unique key.

Workaround, Since unique key is already going to be unique for every row across entire collection, we can define our unique value itself as also 'id' field. So now if we have any updates on addition field apart from unique key we can update them as 'id' field for respective unique key will also be same.

In SQL way,

```
SELECT <unique_key_field> AS id, <unique_key_field>, field1, field2 FROM <table_name>
```